Eclipse PyDev Unresloved Import
I have been researching for long time and none of the proposed solution worked in my case and for that particular library. Im using python project inside Eclipse IDE using pydev extension. For some reason the refrerence in one of the files to the saxoncee package is giving compiler error despite that the code executes successfully (that is quite unique feature of Eclipse IDE for some reason) even I have seen it happen with Java code. It seems like the compilation engine and the execution engine live in totally different universes. Its been quite the painful experience with Eclipse and I'm started to regret moving my code there.
This error doesnt show in Visual Code. Both point to the same Python environment.
Eclipse is giving the unresolved import on the PysaxonProcessor in :
from saxoncee import PySaxonProcessor

The library can be found installed

Again, the code executes fine!
Can someone help please
Update**:
As I suspected this is has to do with this particular package . I just found in thier documentation the following:
Using pylint on a project which uses saxonche
Because the saxonche is a C extension, you will need to either configure Pylint to load the module to avoid pylint errors like:
E0611: No name 'PySaxonProcessor' in module 'saxonche' (no-name-in-module)

The question now how to do that in eclipse. how do I configure this pyinit  and what do I put in it?
Thanks

It seems something is wrong with your preferences or project properties. Java and Python are quite different things, for instance you do not have a Python compiler but a Python interpreter. Here is the documentation you should follow: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

please see my update in the initial post. what is this pyinit and how do I configure it in eclipse?

The Python support is by PyDev which can supported here. PyLint is a lint tool (static code analysis tool) for Python which is also supported by PyDev: https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html I don't think PyLint is related to your root issue. Please show your preferences and your project properties (see my first comment).

When dealing with C sometimes you have to ask PyDev to use the dynamic inference engine (instead of the standard static inference engine).
The way to do that is adding the module you want to Forced Builtins.
In this case you'd add saxoncee there.
Search for Forced Builtins in the Interpreter Configuration in the Getting Started Manual: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for more details.
Now, this is all related to how PyDev sees things... if you are using PyLint (and it seems you have it enabled as E0611: No name 'PySaxonProcessor' in module 'saxonche' (no-name-in-module) seems to be generated by PyLint and not actually PyDev).
In that case you should check https://pylint.org/ to see how to configure it in that case, then create a .pylintrc with the proper configuration in your project directory (so that other PyLint users can also use it), add --rcfile=.pylintrc to your setting in Eclipse (in PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis > PyLint), so that it picks up that configuration.
You can also just disable PyLint if you can't get it to work as you'd like (or even disable the PyDev code analysis if you feel it's getting in the way for you to be productive) in the PyDev settings.

WOW. Amazing after all this work the error disappeared. well not directly for some reason I had to erase the reference and re added again for it to see it and remove the error! even restarting Eclipse did not help. Adding the saxonee to forced bulletins seems to fix the issue. I know that there was something else going. Now the intellisense works as well (kind of). Thanks again.
